# Max size of resources files inside watchOS extension?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos-3

I'm planing to create new watch app that will play some audio files on watchOS 3. I'm gonna have to include at least 10 audio files (m4a), about 50MB inside the extension target. Is there any limitation on including resources in watch app extension target?

I couldn't find any documentation about this. Any suggestion? appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: A watch app is bundled inside an iOS app. It's not a standalone app that is submitted or downloaded on its own. Look at the iOS guidelines.

Comment: Thanks. I know it's bundled but the files will be inside the extension target which of course will not be bundled!

Comment: The watchOS extension is bundled inside the watchOS app, which is bundled inside the iOS app. The watch extension adds to the size of the watch app, which then adds to the size of the iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a size limit of 50MB.

You will receive something similar to this:

`ERROR ITMS-90389: "Size Limit Exceeded. The size of watch application (55MB) has exceeded the 50MB size limit."`

if you try to upload your app to Itunes Connect